# XML Comments in C# don't show summary they show xml

Tags: c#, xml, comments

I have regions and various methods within those regions.  When I add XML comments to the top of the methods and collapse the xml comment it shows something like "///  ..." which is ueseless.  How can I make it show the content inside the summary tag when collapsed.

VS 2008 Pro
.NET 3.5 SP1

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write the summary out all in one line, such as:

```
/// <summary>My summary.</summary>
```

... you will see the summary when collapsed.

Frankly, I don't like this approach, because my summaries are usually longer than fits comfortably on one line.

Comment: I would vote this up but I don't have enough vote power yet.  I would even go as far as its unreasonable at times to fit your summary all in one line.  And <summary></summary> are always on multiple lines by default.  Am I just stuck with this?

Comment: @Matt: I'm afraid so. There may be plugins that can help, but I don't use any myself. This MSDN entry (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx) mentions some of the nifty WPF-based comment rendering that was promised with VS2010; however, it seems to be the case that VS2010 didn't actually ship with the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The collapsed comment block will display the first line of the comment until you expand it.  Therefore, you could format your XML comments to include a representative portion of the summary on the first line:

```
    /// <summary>The most important part of your comment on the first line
    /// and other stuff following on subsequent lines.</summary>
    public static void DoStuff()
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Will collapse to:

```
    /// <summary>The most important part of your comment on the first line ...
    public static void DoStuff() ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I wish microsoft make the collapsed text of a xml comment the value between the <summary></summary>.  This way comments would be somewhat meaningful in the collapsed state as well.